# Storm cannot start use "supervisor.run.worker.as.user: true" option on Windows Server

Tags: apache-storm

Version: 1.2.2

platform: Windows 10

When storm.yaml config use "supervisor.run.worker.as.user: true" option, Storm start failed on Windows 10, and No log in log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running as other users is not supported on Windows.

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/8a475696e908c53f1c06bf1a8f373d8ac0483427/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/daemon/supervisor/RunAsUserContainer.java#L55

Someone would need to provide a Windows compatible variant of this class, as well as a couple of other bits in the code. The issue is tracked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-371 if you'd like to work on it.